# GraphAware support for Dutch NLP

Tags: neo4j, nlp, graphaware

I have a lot of Dutch articles which I'd like to NLP-process within my neo4j database. GraphAware provides a plugin for NLP with OpenNLP. However, when annotating the text it triggers an error with the following message:

`` Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `ga.nlp.annotate`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported language : nl ``

I imagine that I'd need to load the dutch models, however GraphAware doesn't mention anything on this for OpenNLP.

How can I get Graphaware with OpenNLP to work with Dutch text?